# Web API global setup code, also for unit tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2

Say I have some global application setup code, defined in my `Global.asax`, `Application_Start`. For example to disable certificate checking:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // (...)
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        // (...)
    }
}
```

Say I also have a unit test, which depends on the code above to be run. However in my unit test, `Application_Start` is not called as I'm instantiating the controller directly:

```
var controller = new TestSubjectController();
```

Is there some mechanism in ASP.NET or Web API that solves this problem? What would be the best way to define the setup code, preventing duplication in my code?

*Research*
I've went through multiple questions on SO already. Most of them focus on unit testing `Application_Start` itself, however that's not the goal here. Other questions tend to look at testing using the applications external (HTTP) interface, however I'd like being able to instantiate the controller directly in my unit tests.

Comment: And just making a (static) function where you run your code to disable your certificate doens't work? that way you can call it from both your application_start and your unittest

Comment: Sure that would work, but would result in a lot of duplication in my unit tests, calling to this static method. I was hoping for something more out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Batavia's suggestion you could use a `[TestInitialize]` attributed method or your unit testing framework of choices's equivalent to call the common static method for all tests in a certain class which would reduce the duplication you're concerned about.

Comment: Not the solution I was hoping for, but suffices.